# Emotion Library hover effect

Tags: emotion

Im using emotion library for react and im using :hover effects tho how im suppose to attach after the hover an other classname?

like the style goes like this  for e.x 
const button1 = css
 `color:red'
&:hover (tho here when its hovered i wanna color button2*) {color:white}`

*how im suppose to attach it ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (ideally with comments) => https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve